# Android - adjusting text in a grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I am having this problem that text in the Grid View is not fully visible - how can I make the TextView expand so that all the text becomes visible?

Here is what I am getting in the emulator:

[image]

And this is my `mail.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:background="#A9A9A9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="130dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is gridview_row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="64dp" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="64dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:ellipsize="ttt"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your text view that have more then 3 lines in text. Try to set maxline on your text view like this

```
android:maxLines="4"
```

and also the length of text like this

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

may this solve your problem.